# How to remember the state of a popup in Crossrider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, crossrider

I have a popup in Crossrider in which I have a checkbox. It look something like this:

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="div1">
        <label for="checkbox1">Enable Something</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, when the user closes the popup I want the popup to remember the state of the checkbox. So if the user has enabled #checkbox1, I want it to still be enabled next time he opens the popup.

I tried doing this and it does not work:

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#checkbox1').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
            $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);    
        else
            $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);
    })
});
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup content is not preserved between invocations of the popup; hence you must save the state outside the popup scope, usually for small quantities of data such as this in the Crossrider database using [appAPI.db](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.db).

In addition, such code would best be placed in the **crossriderMain** function which is automatically called when the page is ready.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- This meta tag is relevant only for IE -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<script type="text/javascript">
function crossriderMain($) {
  if (appAPI.db.get('checkbox1'))
    $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);    
  else
    $('#checkbox1').prop('checked', false);

  $('#checkbox1').on('change', function(){
    appAPI.db.set('checkbox1', $(this).is(':checked'));
  })
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="div1">
    <label for="checkbox1">Enable Something</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]